# How can i target an image with an a href with jquery?

Tags: jquery, append, label, categories, overlay

I'm trying to add category labels over an a href image with jquery. Now i have the following fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Eddiebouncer/43x6L2bj/
The jquery checks what category is in the link and adds the label. But this also targets text-links (which was to be expected in the end).

How can i target only a href's with the image in it to overlay the label?

Regards, Ed'

HTML

```
<div style="padding:20px;margin-top:40px;">
  Example with 2 images with category A and B. Script generates a category-label accordingly.
</div>
<div class="relative-container">
  <a href="something/category-A/#"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x150" /></a>
</div>
<div class="relative-container">
  <a href="something/category-B/#"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x150" /></a>
</div>
<div style="padding:20px;">
  Here a text link - but this shouldn't be targeted: <a href="something/category-A/#">read more</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[href*="category-A"]').append('<div id="overlay-A">category A</div>');
  $('a[href*="category-B"]').append('<div id="overlay-B">category B</div>');
});
```

CSS

```
.relative-container {
  position: relative;
}

#overlay-A,
#overlay-B {
  display: inline block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

#overlay-A {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 120, 0.75);
}

#overlay-B {
  background: rgba(0, 120, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, use the `.relative-container` class to differentiate for the two

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.relative-container a[href*="category-A"]').append('<div id="overlay-A">category A</div>');

  $('.relative-container a[href*="category-B"]').append('<div id="overlay-B">category B</div>');
});
```

or test if the link has a image

```
$('.relative-container a[href*="category-A"]').each(function() {
   if($(this).find('img').length) {
      $(this).append('<div id="overlay-B">category B</div>');
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick - and it's probably simple, but i was happy to figure out my fiddle sofar ;).
When i implement it to the site it seems to work nicely.

Q. Would there still be a way to differentiate an img link from a text link though?

Cheers, Ed'

Comment: there are no  image links/text links in html/js you may use js to test if a link has a image

Comment: Thanks Madalinivascu, for the added snippet. I'm trying to fiddle it in to make things work, but still the textual link is targeted also?
see: https://jsfiddle.net/Eddiebouncer/43x6L2bj/

Comment: Thank you Madalinivascu. jsfiddle.net/Lna1bxyu seems the best to work with, but i like how you merged/finetuned the category output @ jsfiddle.net/Lna1bxyu/1